# Change RGB to GrayScale in c++

Tags: c++, image-processing, rgb, grayscale

I am trying to convert RGB image to gray scale using average method. But the output that is get is different from the desired output. I'm taking the image and getting the rgb values. I perform average operation and store the averaged and another array of same size of the image. Finally i'm converting the array to Mat and displaying the image.

Input image:

[image: Input image]

Desired output:

[image: desired output]

My output:

[image: my output]

```
int main()
{
 Mat image;

 image =imread("<image_path>");

 int rows=image.rows;
 int cols=image.cols;

 int myArray[rows][cols];


 for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
     myArray[i][j] = 0;
   }
 }

 uint8_t* pixelPtr = (uint8_t*)image.data;

 int cn = image.channels();

 Scalar_<uint8_t> bgrPixel;

 for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)

 {
     for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)

     {
         bgrPixel.val[0] = pixelPtr[i*image.cols*cn + j*cn + 0]; // B

         bgrPixel.val[1] = pixelPtr[i*image.cols*cn + j*cn + 1]; // G

         bgrPixel.val[2] = pixelPtr[i*image.cols*cn + j*cn + 2]; // R

         int average = (bgrPixel.val[0]+bgrPixel.val[1]+bgrPixel.val[2])/3;

         myArray[i][j]=average;


     }

 }

 Mat averaged_image(Size(rows, cols), CV_8UC3, myArray, Mat::AUTO_STEP);

 imwrite("<path to save the image>",averaged_image);

 imshow("averaged_image",averaged_image);

 waitKey(0);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically your code is not valid C++, as standard C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Please use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i get the same output even after using  for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<cols;j++){

    Vec3b rgb_color=image.at<Vec3b>(i,j);
    int average=(rgb_color.val[0]+rgb_color.val[1]+rgb_color.val[2])/3;

    myArray[i][j]=average;

   }
 }

Comment: Nevertheless, it doesn't help to have non-standard code in your example. If someone interested in helping doesn't have a compiler with the VLA extension, you leave the conversion job up to that person.

Comment: Assuming OpenCV, the [`Mat` constructor you use](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a9fa74fb14362d87cb183453d2441948f) for `averaged_image` is probably expecting the image data in the same way that you use for `pixelPtr`: A single contiguous array *of bytes*.

Comment: ***And*** you need to set all three components of the output data to the average color value. Or use a different format than `CV_8UC3` which expects three color values (use instead `CV_8UC1` to have only a single color value).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is there any other way rather than converting the array to Mat and displaying the image to directly displaying the image using myArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating `Mat averaged_image`,

```
 Mat averaged_image(Size(rows, cols), CV_8UC3, myArray, Mat::AUTO_STEP);
```

you need to use `CV_32S` not `CV_8UC3` because your array element is not three chars, it's one 32-bit int.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I've changed the array to uint8_t and when creating the ```Mat averaged_image```  i've changed it ```CV_8U```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function `cvtColor`:

```
cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Bonus: this function does correct weighting of the channels, because simple averaging may not be the right thing to do.